# Connect to database using perl

Tags: perl, dbi

I have one script in which I am connecting to database and trying to eexecute the sql query. My code is like this

```
use DBI;
$dbh = DBI->connect('Databasename', 'uid','pswd');
my $sth = $dbh->prepare ("select * from Tablename");
$sth->execute();
my @row_ary = $sth->hetshrow_array;
foreach $item (@row_ary)
{
print "$item\n";
}
```

when I am trying to execute this code I am getting the following error message

```
Can't connect to data source 'Databasename' because I can't work out what driver to use (it doesn't seem to contain a 'dbi:driver:' prefix and the DBI_DRIVER env var is not set) at demo.pl line 2
```

Can anybody please suggest me why I am getting this message. What is the configuration I need to do for executing sql queries.

Thanks

Comment: Seems to me that the error message is really very clear. You don't have 'dbi:<drivername>' at the start of your connection string. Perhaps you should try reading the documentation for DBI and the DBD that you are using.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

DBI is flexible in that it supports multiple database servers (MySQL, Sybase, Oracle, etc). The first parameter you pass in to DBI->connect is a DSN (Data Source Name), not a database name. The format of the DSN is:

`dbi:Driver:databasename`

If your database is MySQL, you would use `mysql` for the driver:

`dbi:mysql:databasename`

Here's [more info on DBI](http://search.cpan.org/~timb/DBI/DBI.pm).

Comment: You can find the name of the drivers by search for DBD on cpan. e.g. Postgresql is Pg because the module is DBD::Pg. You can find more info about connection to the specific database by looking in the appropriate DBD's docs.